# Tensorflow 2.0.0: AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'as_numpy_iterator'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I am testing tensorflow `tf.data.Dataset` method `as_numpy_iterator` using `tensorflow 2.0.0`. According to the official documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#as_numpy_iterator, this function allows directly inspecting the content of a tensorflow dataset. But when I try the given example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3]) 
for element in dataset.as_numpy_iterator(): 
  print(element)
```

There occurs an error: `AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'as_numpy_iteractor'`. I am wondering if this method is just newly added, beyond the support of tensorflow 2.0.0. If so, is there an alternative to checking the dataset content as the `as_numpy_iterator()`?

Comment: What's wrong with `for element in dataset: `?

Comment: you are referring the tensorflow 2.1 documentaion  but you are using it one tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to the documentation that you provided points to

> TensorFlow Core r2.1

Updating your `tensorflow` version to version `2.1` should solve the issue;

The method .`as_numpy_iterator()` is not present in TensorFlow 2.0, but only in TensorFlow >= 2.1